# Strcmp like behaviour applied on list of objects in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, list, stl

In cpp, i want to know if there is any better way to do the following:

```
bool operator<(...) {
    if( x < X )
      return true;
    else if ( x > X )
      return false;
    else if ( y < Y )
      return true;
    else if ( y > Y )
      return false;
    else if ( z < Z )
      return true;
    else if ( z > Z )
      return false;
    .... so on
    else
      return false;
}
```

This looks similar to applying strcmp kind of functionality between lists [x,y,z,...] and [X,Y,Z,...]. Here the types of x and y ( or y and z or X and Y ) may not be same, but the pairs (x,X) and (y,Y) and (z,Z) ,... are of the same type or have the operator < and > defined for them.

Is there any better way to achieve the above functionality other than having a huge if-else-if block in C++.

@Edited
Usecase for the above method is something like this.
I have a class

```
NextHop{
  macAddr : MacAddr;
  intf : Interface;
... so on
}
```

Here MacAddr is a class, and it's comparison operator '<' just compares the strings, and the Interface is a class, which compares two integer values. Now i want to implement an operator< for NextHop.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The question seems pretty valid, there may be good answers for that, including some using C++ macros.

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp It's not much of a "strcmp libe behavior" really. And much to broad since we don't know what the "lists" are. Perhaps it could be solved with a simple loop, but it's impossible to say since we don't know any details.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : it kind of is - it's a lexicographical comparison.

Comment: @Pankaj Jangid: Would you please add input data and expected output to your question by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50870180/edit)?

Comment: As a possible way to solve your problem (without really knowing enough details to actually be able to help you), have you considered [template parameter packs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) and [fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)?

Comment: some combination of [`std::lexicographical_compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) and types with a common base class (if that's possible) would be my first attempt to get it to work. But a lot depends on what it is that you're *actually* trying to achieve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
bool operator<(...) {
  return std::tie(x,y,z,...) < std::tie(X,Y,Z,...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In some future C++ version, you can use the new comparison operator, `<=>`, to implement a "generic compare function for any type" (which returns a similar value to `strcmp`, -1, 0 or 1, based on first being smaller, both equal or greater). [This will only help, really, for the intent of writing a more generic comparison operator for a type - so not really help if you have three pairs of individual variables]

However, for current versions of C++, if you have MANY variables [member variables or general variables] of different types, you will ultimately have to do the compare for one at a time. For the particular pattern above, you can shorten the sequence this way, but if there are more than three values, it's still getting quite lengthy...

```
if (x < X) return true;
if (x == X)
{
    if (y < Y) return true;
    if (y == Y) return z < Z;
}
return false;
```

The above would be how you check a date is less than another, for example, when entered as year, month, day - assuming `X` is year, `Y` month and `Z` day.

For large numbers of values of the same type, you can of course use `std::lexicographical_compare`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is

```
bool operator<(...) {
    if( x != X )
      return (x < X);
    else if (y != Y)
      return (y < Y);
    else if (z != Z)
      return (z < Z);
      .... so on
    else
      return false;
}
```

which halves your compares